# SharePoint 2013: Event ID 2: Session “SharePointDiagnostics” failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, database

We're on 2013 CU 3/15 and I'm seeing this error once/twice a day on one of our front end servers.

> Event ID 2: Session “SharePointDiagnostics” failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

[I've tried this resolution but the remediation he discusses](https://jerryyasir.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/how-to-fix-sharepointdiagnostics-event-id-2/) (practically the only Google result) isn't visible in our setup - the line he says to comment-out isn't present.

Comment: are you getting the same error as mentioned in blog when you browse the reports?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the same error.  But I looked in the logs, and though I didn't find a correlation id, I did find the log entry that matched the Event Viewer entry: `UserProfileDBCache.GetChangedDBItemsPrimaryKeys: m_AllPropertyIDs = 1;3;9;2;5009;7;23;13;14;22;5065;5061;5062;5040;5042;5091;5092;5093;5096;5097;5098;`

Comment: Did you check the wss Logging database for the stored procedure as you mentioned you cannt find it? i am thinking may be you checking with content DB

Comment: I was looking here: WSS_UsageApplication > Programmability > Stored Procedures > proc_GetSlowestPages

Comment: Hi Travis, I am facing same issue have you  ever managed to resolve it? Just to mention I can browse to the health reports without issue.